# give 2 names to the values from the leaves for translation

Tags: flutter, dart

I have map<dynamic, String> with units and names.
[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg2QP.png[1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg2QP.png%5B1%5D)
How to add String to Dropdownbutton?
Dropdownbutton shows this problem "The argument type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'."
Dropdownbutton code:

```
.map(
                (e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: e == TimeUnit.calendarYear
                      ? Text("year")
                      : e.toString().length == 3
                          ? Text(e)
                          : Text(e.toString().split(".")[1]),
                  value: e,
                ),
              )
```

Comment: Can provide your Dropdownbutton  code snippet?

Comment: yes https://github.com/Vignesh-Ganesan-008/Unit_Convertor-Flutter/blob/main/lib/widgets/DropDownBox.dart